# Cost of Cloud Sql to Cloud Storage Data transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have 300 GBs of data in Cloud SQL of Google Cloud Platform. The data is coming in every second, our idea is to keep only current month's data into Cloud SQL and put the old data (data of previous months) into Cloud Storage (coldline storage). What will be the cost of exporting and transferring it into Cloud Storage. (on google cloud platform price list I don't get the information about these transfers).
And what frequency should I schedule this task to transfer old data into Cloud Storage i.e. Monthly or quarterly etc.

Answer (score 0):

0

If you use the export feature of Cloud SQL, you directly query Cloud SQL and export to Cloud Storage.

If the Cloud Storage is in the same region as the Cloud SQL instance, you won't pay egress for your export. Therefore 0!

Be aware that the export is performed by your database (the queries are ran), and you can have performance issues when you run it. Perform it during a low usage of your database.